# Is StageVideo masking and tweening possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Want to incorporate StageVideo for an iOS for desktop application since the latest AIRSDK3.8 finally supports StageVideo.

However, I also need to be able to somehow tween and mask it to create a 'parallax' effect.

Does any one know if this is possible since it is no longer on the display list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masking `StageVideo` is incredibly easy. All you have to do is display an object over it. Since StageVideo is rendered below the stage, everything in the DisplayList renders on top of it. So after you mask/make your background transparent, just through a DisplayObject on the stage over the area your video occupies and you have a mask.

Tweening is possible. It's dirty, but it is possible. See [this blog post](http://flexsupreme.com/2012/08/23/slide-in-stagewebview/) I wrote last year about tweening `StageWebView` (which is displayed in much the same way, just over the display list rather than under it). It should also includes the test app I used.

The code from that post in case my blog ever goes down (unlikely since WebHostingHub likes to auto-renew my account two months before it is set to expire...)

```
import flash.net.*;

private var swv:StageWebView;
private var startX:Number;
private var finalX:int;
private var repeatCount:int;

private function addedToStage():void{
this.startX = -600;
this.finalX = 120;
this.repeatCount = 100;
this.swv = new StageWebView();
this.swv.stage = this.stage;
this.swv.viewPort = new Rectangle( startX, 50, 600, stage.stageHeight - 50 );
this.swv.loadURL( 'http://flexsupreme.com' );
this.swv.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,this.loadComplete);
}

private function loadComplete(e:Event = null):void{
var t:Timer = new Timer( 1000 / stage.frameRate, this.repeatCount );
t.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, this.slide );
t.start();
}

private function slide(e:TimerEvent = null):void{
var change:int = Math.round ( ( this.finalX - this.startX ) / this.repeatCount );
if ( this.swv != null ) {
this.swv.viewPort = new Rectangle( this.swv.viewPort.x + change, 50, 600, stage.stageHeight - 50);
}
}
```

You could also use a Tween library like Greensock if you wanted. You would just tween the viewport. I can't remember if you need to re-set the viewport to apply the changes or not (probably do), but Greensock offers an "onUpdate" callback in its `to()` methods that you can use to do that.